# Llamar a un endpoint con delay

Tags: javascript, axios, promesas

Tengo un inconveniente: Deseo hacer un llamado al endpoint de un api cada 5 segundos, pero cuando agrego la llamada de axios, se empieza a ejecutar todas las consultas a la vez y me causa un 429 (Too Many Request):

Este es mi código que me muestra los datos cada 5 segundos:

```js
// Este código me muestra los datos de mis usuarios cada 5 segundos
const deleteUser = (company, email, delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({company, email})
        }, delay * 5000)
    })

}

axios.get('users_delete.json') // Archivo con mis usuarios
    .then(res => {
        const users = res.data
        
        let promises = Promise.all(users.map((user, i) => {
            return deleteUser(user.company_id, user.email, i)
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }))

        console.log(promises.then(res => console.log(res) ))
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Pero si coloco la llamada de axios así, no funciona:

```js
const deleteUser = (company, email, delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8088', {
                params: {
                    company,
                    email,
                    status: 'Aprobado'
                }
            })
            .then(res => resolve(res.data))
            .catch(err => reject(err.response.data))
        }, delay * 1000)
    })

}

axios.get('users_delete.json')
    .then(res => {
        const users = res.data
        
        let promises = Promise.all(users.map((user, i) => {
            return deleteUser(user.company_id, user.email, i)
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }))

        console.log(promises.then(res => console.log(res) ))
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Si alguno pudiera orientarme o decirme cómo podría entenderlo mejor, se lo agradecería

Comment: en tu primer timeout tienes a 5 segundos, en el segundo lo tienes a 1

Comment: En este caso te sugiero que uses sockets o websockets, se considera mala práctica estar llamando tu API cada segundo, eso te consumirá mucho recurso a tu servidor, dejando sin servicio a tus clientes, o puedes aumentar el tiempo de tu delay, a 10 segundos, que seria `delay * 10000)`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberias poner un intervalo, de todas forma, ten en cuenta lo que dice [Daniel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/51552/daniel), esto consumira muchos recursos.

```js
function request() {
    //axios.get()...
  console.log("a")
}

setInterval(() => {
  request()
}, 5000)//5 segundos
```

en la llamada de axios: